# Laravel Admin Directory

Tags: admin, laravel-5, directory-structure

I am trying to separate my admin code from my public code, I want to create 2 different directories in my app folder and resources folder, 1 directory named backend which contains all my admin code and another named frontend which contains public related code.

Each directory will have their own separate controllers.

Basically something like this:

```
-App
  --frontend
  --backend

-resources
  --views
    ---frontend
    ---backend.
```

If there is a better way to do this i would also like to know.

Answer (score 0):

By default you composer.json is autoload all in app. So you can make the structure which you described above.

Frontend and backend separating usually  used for `Controllers`, in this case you need to make a correct namespace.

With `views` you would'n have any porblems. Just make a correct path when you calling your views.
For example:
`view(frontend/index);` // you can use dot instead of `/`

Comment: Concerning this in my routes.php file, supposing i am using resource, how will my route know which namespace to point to or does the routes file ignore namespaces completely?

Comment: you can configure namespaces for routes.